# Open source database library with C API

Tags: linux, open-source, library, database, embedded-database

I am looking for the open source library similiar to SQLite. The requirements are:

- C API
- C/C++ backend
- server-less
- configration properties (e.g. no dynamic allocations, crash tolerance)
- open source
- Linux target plafrorm

What would you recommend?

I was searching through the web but haven't found a proper candidate. The target platform is an embedded system so more lightweight - the better.